# How to strip unix timestamps from a string PHP

Tags: php, regex, unix, timestamp

Lets say I have the following string:

```
$string = 'Th1s 1s my 5tr1ng with a timestamp 1357002120 and another timestamp here 1357002120.';
```

What I want is to return a string, without the two timestamps, but leave any other numbers intact.

So, the output should be:

'Th1s 1s my 5tr1ng with a timestamp and another timestamp here.'

I figure some sort of regex would be able to do it but i've no idea where to start.

Comment: and how we determine another number is not a `timestamp` ?

Comment: How do you define a UNIX timestamp? Just *any number surrounded by word boundaries*? Because `1` and `-40` are UNIX timestamps too.

Comment: Excellent point, and one which quite honestly I hadn't considered. The scope of the requirement within the application would be that the timestamp would need to be within the last 7 days. So, I guess we can safely assume it to be 10 digits long and for the sake of arguement lets assume that every 10 or 11 digit long numerical value would be a timestamp within this variable.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution you can later develop your own:

```
<?php
$string = 'Th1s 1s my 5tr1ng with a timestamp 1357002120 and another timestamp here 1357002120.';
echo preg_replace("#\d{10,11}#", "", $string);
?>
```